# Convert nested "for loop" into module

Tags: c++, c++14, modularity

I have a monolithic piece of c++ code. I have successfully modularized existing functions. My assignment requires that modularize certain parts of main(). In this case there is a nested "for loop" that I wish to turn into a module. It has a function call to an exiting module. I need the new module to return an array "number_of_ants". What is the best way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linear.h"
int main(){
int length     = 70;
int* number_of_ants = new int[length*length]; 
int total_ants = 40000;

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        int n = linear(i, j, length, length);
        number_of_ants[n] = ((long long)(n+1)*total_ants)/(length*length) - ((long long) 
                            (n)*total_ants)/(length*length);
        }
   }
}
```

I need to return number_of_ants[] which is an array.
Note: function linear() just takes data that is naturally 2D (row, column) and turns it into a vector.

Comment: Maybe a function along the lines of: `int* calc_num_ants(int length, int total_ants)`?

Comment: Ideally you would use `std::vector` instead of raw array `int[]`, since you tag C++14

Comment: Summer - what would the call and return statements look like. I am pretty new to c++.. Thanks

Comment: Please show how far you have got. Can you move all of the main code into a void func(void) and call it? Show that please and describe what is wrong about it and you will get help focusing on the first problem you describe. If not it is probably time to find a tutorial on function calling  follow it and then do the void func(void). Have look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Note that the currently shown code does not need a return value. Consider making a [mre] of code which uses the required return value for something.